# uploading multiple photos in Firefox causes lost session in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, session, firefox, webforms, telerik

When We use Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX's telerik:RadAsyncUpload control to upload multiple photos (have preview before being uploaded), it works on all browsers in my local dev environment and our test server. It works on Chrome and IE in our beta and prod servers. But it doesn't work on Firefox in our beta and prod server; it kicks user out and redirect them to login page. We debugged into it and found the reason is that the session is lost. For some reason, Firefox will cause session lost.

Our beta and prod servers have load balancer while our test server doesn't. But even try individual ip address (not using domain name) in beta/prod, it still have the same problem.

Our code is based on the following link's sample code.

http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/preview-image-before-it-have-been-uploaded-with-radasyncupload

I am not sure if this problem is related to Telerik control, or is it just a FireFox problem. It seems to me more like the latter.

This problem is really weird. It has been several weeks and we are still not able to solve it.

Comment: Have you placed a session timeout attribute from web.config?

Comment: Do all servers in the farm share the same session? Do they have the same machine key? Is the temporary upload folder a single location on a network mapped to all servers as a virtual folder? Hint: the answers should be Yes to all

Comment: @abramlimpin, no we don't. I think the default is 20 minutes. The thing is that all other browsers work.

Comment: @rdmptn, I am not sure about the answer since some other guy takes care of the serrvers, but based on my experience, the answers to the first two questions are yes. For the third question, the answer is no, as far as I know, Telerik automatically upload images to this folder \App_Data\RadUploadTemp. So in our case, each server has its own folder. But do you think this is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure but possibly, yes. There is a property that sets this folder location too, it is not hardcoded.

Comment: @rdmptn, thanks. we found solution, please see my answer below.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Wouldn't have crossed my mind

Answer (score 0):

We have fixed the problem. The problem is still FireFox's bug, as indicated in that post

http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/preview-image-before-it-have-been-uploaded-with-radasyncupload

The trick part is how to fix this bug: delay `10 ms` before calling `showThumbnail(...)`. Notice you cannot put the delay inside `showThumbnail(...)`, that doesn't work.

```
window.CurrentFileUploaded = function (radAsyncUpload, args) {
    ...
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) // if FireFox, delay 10 ms. This is the fix for FireFox bug!!! 
    {
        setTimeout(function () { showThumbnail(...); }, 10);
    }
    else
    {
        showThumbnail(...); 
    }

}
```